# Play/Stop MP3 Queue with Naudio or other

Tags: c#, charts, queue, mp3

I have a problem to stop/pause a Mp3 Queue. Any help please?
I use this class from Githup. it work fine but can't stop it:

```
    public class playr
    {
        private Queue<string> playlist;
        private IWavePlayer player = new WaveOutEvent();
        private WaveStream fileWaveStream;

        public playr()
        {

        }
        public playr(List<string> startingPlaylist)
        {
            playlist = new Queue<string>(startingPlaylist);
        }
        public void PlaySong()
        {
            if (playlist.Count < 1)
            {
                return;
            }

                if (player != null && player.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Stopped)
                {
                    player.Stop();
                }
                if (fileWaveStream != null)
                {
                    fileWaveStream.Dispose();
                }
                if (player != null)
                {
                    player.Dispose();
                    player = null;
                }

                player = new WaveOutEvent();


                fileWaveStream = new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(playlist.Dequeue(), new Mp3FileReader.FrameDecompressorBuilder(waveFormat => new NLayer.NAudioSupport.Mp3FrameDecompressor(waveFormat)));
                var stream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(fileWaveStream);

            player.Init(fileWaveStream);
            player.Play();
            player.PlaybackStopped += (sender, evn) => { PlaySong(); };


        }


    }
```

I popup mp3 files from a datagridview. The goal is playing mp3 sounds and drawing charts.

```
 private void Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
              playlist = new List<string>();
                for (int item = 0; item < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; item++)
                  {
                      playlist.Add(@"mp3Conversion\sounds\" + dataGridView1.Rows[item].Cells["mp3"].Value.ToString());

                  }

                playr playr = new playr(playlist);

                playr.PlaySong();

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    }
```

It wont to stop when I click stop button. is there a way to add a notifier or manage queue ?

```
    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            var playr = new playr(playlist);

            playr.stopit();

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's not too late to help you

You can't pause, because you are losing the reference to the object defining a new object

You could try to define the object as static object to solve this problem, but you have to be very careful disposing the object or access to it from multi thread

A very little example

```
    public class playr
{
    private Queue<string> playlist;
    public static IWavePlayer player = new WaveOutEvent();
    // private WaveStream fileWaveStream;

    public playr()
    {

    }
    public playr(List<string> startingPlaylist)
    {
        playlist = new Queue<string>(startingPlaylist);
    }

    public void PlaySong()
    {
        if (playlist.Count < 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (player != null && player.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Stopped)
        {
            player.Stop();
        }

        if (player != null)
        {
            player.Dispose();
            player = null;
        }

        player = new WaveOutEvent();

        var audioFilePath = playlist.First();

        var fileWaveStream = new AudioFileReader(audioFilePath);

        player.Init(fileWaveStream);
        player.Play();
        player.PlaybackStopped += (sender, evn) => { PlaySong(); };
    }
}
```

Then you can handle the "player" object from form view